# How can I create a list Array with the cursor data in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-cursor

How can I create a list Array (the list display First Alphabet when scroll) with the cursor data?

Comment: You want to create a `ArrayList` with the data of a cursor?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Go through every element in the `Cursor`, and add them one by one to the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant> mArrayList = new ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant>();
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    // The Cursor is now set to the right position
    mArrayList.add(mCursor.getWhateverTypeYouWant(WHATEVER_COLUMN_INDEX_YOU_WANT));
}
```

(replace `WhateverTypeYouWant` with whatever type you want to make a `ArrayList` of, and `WHATEVER_COLUMN_INDEX_YOU_WANT` with the column index of the value you want to get from the cursor.)

Comment: Hi, The important thing I want to do is display "Fist character" in my List. After I get all data from cursor, I don't know how to convert it to an String[] Array to get "First character". It look something like this char firstLetter = mString[firstVisibleItem].charAt(0);

Comment: Friends: the for loop above is not completly right (condition and increment anre swapped). Use `for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {}`

Comment: This type of loop is kind of awful to read. The solution from @PearsonArtPhoto is way more elegant and easier to read.

Comment: What do you mean by **getWhateverTypeYouWant**?  Is that a real method.

Answer (score 41):

One quick correction: the for loop above skips the first element of the cursor.
To include the first element, use this:

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
mCursor.moveToFirst();
while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
     mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_NAME))); //add the item
     mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: very good point imbrizi. This is a much better way to loop through the elements of the Cursor

Comment: how to add two or more column value??

Answer (score 23):

Even better than @imbrizi's answer is this:

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
     mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_NAME))); //add the item
}
```

`moveToNext()` will return false if there isn't anything left, so this reduces the SLOC by a few, and is easier to see.

Even better is to get the column index outside of the loop.

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
int columnIndex=mCursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_NAME)
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
     mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(columnIndex)); //add the item
}
```

Comment: The only correct way to iterate through the Cursor. Other two answers are just....wrong :|

Comment: Except in weird scenarios, you can usually externalize the getColumnIndex outside the loop

Answer (score 3):

This one worked really well for me because I wanted an arraylist of objects:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = ...

while(c.moveToNext()) {
    myList.add(new MyObject(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column1")), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("column2")));        
}
c.close();
```

Just make a POJO `MyObject` and make sure it has a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can use this extension:

```
fun <T> Cursor.toList(block: (Cursor) -> T) : List<T> {
    return mutableListOf<T>().also { list ->
        if (moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(block.invoke(this))
            } while (moveToNext())
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
val listOfIds = cursor.toList { 
    // create item from cursor. For example get id:
    it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex("_id"))
}
```